# How to Download a File after POSTing data using FastAPI?

Tags: python, html, file, download, fastapi

I am creating a web application that receives some text, converts the text into  speech, and returns an mp3 file, which is saved to a temporary directory.

I want to be able to download the file from the html page (i.e., the frontend), but I don't know how to do that properly.

I know with Flask you can do this:

```py
from app import app
from flask import Flask, send_file, render_template
    
@app.route('/')
def upload_form():
    return render_template('download.html')

@app.route('/download')
def download_file():
    path = "html2pdf.pdf"

    return send_file(path, as_attachment=True)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

HTML Example:

```html
<!doctype html>
<title>Python Flask File Download Example</title>
<h2>Download a file</h2>
<p><a href="{{ url_for('.download_file') }}">Download</a></p>
```

So how do I replicate this with FastAPI?

FastAPI Code:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, Request, Response, UploadFile
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
from fastapi.responses import FileResponse, HTMLResponse, StreamingResponse
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
from gtts import gTTS

templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")


def text_to_speech(language:str, text: str) -> str:
    tts = gTTS(text=text, lang=language, slow=False)
    tts.save("./temp/welcome.mp3")
    #os.system("mpg321 /temp/welcome.mp3")
    return "Text to speech conversion successful"


@app.get("/")
def home(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {"request": request})

@app.get("/text2speech")
async def home(request: Request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = await request.form()
        if form["message"] and form["language"]:
            language = form["language"]
            text = form["message"]
            translate = text_to_speech(language, text)
            path = './temp/welcome.mp3'
            value = FileResponse("./temp/welcome.mp3", media_type="audio/mp3")
            return value
    # return templates.TemplateResponse(
    #     "index.html",
    #     {"request": request, "message": text, "language": language, "download": value},
    # )
```

Sample HTML File:

```html
<!doctype html>
<title>Download MP3 File</title>
<h2>Download a file</h2>
<p><a href="{{ url_for('text2speech') }}">Download</a></p>
```

Comment: Have you read anything about Jinja templating? I would start there and see how you can insert a variable somewhere in the template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `Form` keyword to define [`Form-data`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-forms/) in your endpoint, and more specifically, use `Form(...)` to make a parameter *required*, instead of using `await request.form()` and manually checking if the user submitted the *required* parameters. After processing the received data and generating the audio file, you can use [`FileResponse`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/#fileresponse) to return the file to the user. **Note:** use the `headers` argument in `FileResponse` to set the [`Content-Disposition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) header using the `attachment` parameter—as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71639658/17865804)—to have the file downloaded to your device. Failing to set the `headers`, or using the `inline` parameter isntead, would lead to [`405 Method Not Allowed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/405) error, as, in that case, the browser would attempt accessing the file using a `GET` request, in order to display the file contents inline (however, only `POST` requests are allowed to your `/text2speech` endpoint). Have a look at **Option 1** in the examples below.

If you wanted the `/text2speech` endpoint supporting both `GET` and `POST` requests (as shown in your question), you could either (1) use `@app.api_route("/text2speech", methods=["GET", "POST"])` and use `request.method` to check whether it is a `GET` or `POST` request (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75715292/17865804) for a working example), or (2) define two different endpoints with the following decorators on each one, i.e., `@app.post('/text2speech')` and `@app.get('/text2speech')` (Side note: These decorators could also be used on the same endpoint/function, and then use `request.method` as described in (1) option). However, you don't necessarily need to do that in this case.

Additionally, you have added a `Download` hyperlink to your template for the user to download the file. However, you haven't provided any information as to how you expect this to work. This wouldn't work in a scenario where you don't have `static` files, but dynamically generated audio files (as in your case), as well as multiple users accessing the API at the same time; unless, for example, you generated random UUIDs for the filenames and saved the files in a [`StaticFiles`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/static-files/) directory—or added that unique identifier as a query/path parameter (you could also use cookies instead, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73137093/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73155629/17865804)) to the URL in order to identify the file to be downloaded—and sent the URL back to the user. In that case, you would need a Javascript interface/library, such as [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), to make an asynchronous `HTTP` request—as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71665594/17865804)—in order to get the URL to the file and display it in the `Download` hyperlink. Have a look at **Option 2** below. **Note:** The example in Option 2 uses a simple `dict` to map the filepaths to UUIDs, for demo purposes. In a real-world scenario, where multiple users access the API and several [workers](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/deployment/server-workers/) might be used, you may consider using a database storage, or Key-Value stores (Caches), as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71260288/how-to-share-variables-between-http-requests-in-fastapi/71537393#71537393) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65699375/17865804). You would also need to have a mechanism for deleting the files from the database and disk, once they have been downloaded, as well as make sure that users do not have unauthorised access to other users' audio files.

### Option 1

**app.py**

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, Form
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
from fastapi.responses import FileResponse
import os

app = FastAPI()
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")

@app.get('/')
def main(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {"request": request})

@app.post('/text2speech')
def convert(request: Request, message: str = Form(...), language: str = Form(...)):
    # do some processing here
    filepath = './temp/welcome.mp3'
    filename = os.path.basename(filepath)
    headers = {'Content-Disposition': f'attachment; filename="{filename}"'}
    return FileResponse(filepath, headers=headers, media_type="audio/mp3")
```

An alternative to the above would be to read the file data inside your endpoint—**or, in case the data were fully loaded into memory beforehand**, such as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71639658/17865804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71643439/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71728386/17865804)—and return a custom [`Response`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/#response) directly, as shown below:

```py
from fastapi import Response

@app.post('/text2speech')
   ...
    with open(filepath, "rb") as f:
        contents = f.read()  # file contents could be already fully loaded into RAM
    
    headers = {'Content-Disposition': f'attachment; filename="{filename}"'}
    return Response(contents, headers=headers, media_type='audio/mp3')
```

In case you had to **return a file that is too large to fit into memory**—e.g., if you have 8GB of RAM, you can’t load a 50GB file—you could use [`StreamingResponse`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/#streamingresponse), which would load the file into memory in chunks and process the data one chunk at a time (If you find `yield from f` being rather slow, please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73843234/17865804) for faster alternatives):

```py
from fastapi.responses import StreamingResponse

@app.post('/text2speech')
    ...
    def iterfile():
        with open(filepath, "rb") as f:
            yield from f

    headers = {'Content-Disposition': f'attachment; filename="{filename}"'}
    return StreamingResponse(iterfile(), headers=headers, media_type="audio/mp3")
```

templates/**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Convert Text to Speech</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <form method="post" action="http://127.0.0.1:8000/text2speech">
         message : <input type="text" name="message" value="This is a sample message"><br>
         language : <input type="text" name="language" value="en"><br>
         <input type="submit" value="submit">
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

##### Using JavaScript to download the file

In case you used a JavaScript interface, such as Fetch API, in the frontend to issue the file-download request—instead of using an HTML `<form>`, as demonstrated above—please have  a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73414443/17865804), as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71195901/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71193588/17865804) on how to download the file in the frontend through JavaScript.

### Option 2

**app.py**

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, Form
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
from fastapi.responses import FileResponse
import uuid
import os

app = FastAPI()
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")

files = {}

@app.get('/')
def main(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {"request": request})

@app.get('/download')
def download_file(request: Request, fileId: str):
    filepath = files.get(fileId)
    if filepath:
        filename = os.path.basename(filepath)
        headers = {'Content-Disposition': f'attachment; filename="{filename}"'}
        return FileResponse(filepath, headers=headers, media_type='audio/mp3')    
    
@app.post('/text2speech')
def convert(request: Request, message: str = Form(...), language: str = Form(...)):
    # do some processing here
    filepath = './temp/welcome.mp3'
    file_id = str(uuid.uuid4())
    files[file_id] = filepath
    file_url = f'/download?fileId={file_id}'
    return {"fileURL": file_url}
```

templates/**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Convert Text to Speech</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <form method="post" id="myForm">
         message : <input type="text" name="message" value="This is a sample message"><br>
         language : <input type="text" name="language" value="en"><br>
         <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="submitForm()">
      </form>

      <a id="downloadLink" href=""></a>

      <script type="text/javascript">
         function submitForm() {
             var formElement = document.getElementById('myForm');
             var data = new FormData(formElement);
             fetch('/text2speech', {
                   method: 'POST',
                   body: data,
                 })
                 .then(response => response.json())
                 .then(data => {
                   document.getElementById("downloadLink").href = data.fileURL;
                   document.getElementById("downloadLink").innerHTML = "Download";
                 })
                 .catch(error => {
                   console.error(error);
                 });
         }
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

### Removing a File after it's been downloaded

For **Option 1** above, to remove a file after it has been downloaded by the user, you can simply define a [`BackgroundTask`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/background-tasks/) to be run *after* returning the response. For example:

```py
from fastapi import BackgroundTasks
import os

@app.post('/text2speech')
def convert(request: Request, background_tasks: BackgroundTasks, ...):
    filepath = 'welcome.mp3'
    # ...
    background_tasks.add_task(os.remove, path=filepath)
    return FileResponse(filepath, headers=headers, media_type="audio/mp3")
```

For **Option 2**, however, you would have to make sure to delete the key (i.e., `file_id`) pointing to the given filepath from the cache as well. Hence, you should create a background task function, as shown below:

```py
from fastapi import BackgroundTasks
import os

files = {}

def remove_file(filepath, fileId):
    os.remove(filepath)
    del files[fileId]
       
@app.get('/download')
def download_file(request: Request, fileId: str, background_tasks: BackgroundTasks):
    filepath = files.get(fileId)
    if filepath:
        # ...
        background_tasks.add_task(remove_file, filepath=filepath, fileId=fileId)
        return FileResponse(filepath, headers=headers, media_type='audio/mp3')
```

More details and examples on background tasks can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74508996/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73283272/17865804).

Comment: Wow what a well explained answer  thank you very much I think the second option is what I'll use.