# cannot play media audio with streming response fastapi

Tags: python, response, fastapi

I just learned how to return audio as a streaming response in FastAPI but for some reason when I tried to implement StreamingResponse into my project it didn't work but also didn't produce any errors, only the audio couldn't be played like this
[image]

this the program:

```
@router.get("/get-audio-streming/{audio_id}")
async def get_audio_streming(audio_id: int, access_token: str = Header(...)):
result = await check_access_token_expired(access_token=access_token)
if result is True:
    return RedirectResponse(url=config.redirect_uri_page_masuk, status_code=401)
elif result is False:
    return RedirectResponse(url=config.redirect_uri_page_masuk, status_code=401)
else:
    user_id = result

try:
    user = await userdata.filter(user_id=user_id).first()
    audio_data = await logaudio.filter(user_id=user_id, audio_id=audio_id).first()
    if audio_data:
        blob_to_wav(audio_data.audio_file)
        def iterfile():  
            with open('voice.wav', mode="rb") as file_like: 
                yield from file_like
        return StreamingResponse(content=iterfile(), media_type='audio/wav')
    else:
        response = pesan_response(email=user.email, pesan=f'audio data dengan log-audio {audio_id} tidak ditemukan')
        return JSONResponse(response, status_code=404)
except Exception as e:
    raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=str(e))
```

can somebody helpme with this eror

Comment: You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73240097/17865804) helpful.

Comment: @Chris I've tried it but it seems like the error is different