# FastAPI for file upload and minio for storage and share link

Tags: python, angular, fastapi, minio

```
@router.post("/upload_image",tags=['Upload Endpoints'])
async def upload_profile(file: UploadFile, user: User =Depends(get_current_user),db:Session=Depends(get_db)):
    '''Endpoint for profile image'''
    if is_profile_acceptable(file.filename):
        f = await file.read()
        if len(f) >= 5242880 :
            raise HTTPException(400,detail="File size exceeds 5 Mb!")

        extension = file.filename.split('.')[-1]
        file_name=file.filename.split('.')[-2]

        profile = "profile"
        up_name = f"{file_name}-{profile}.{extension}"

        file = io.BytesIO(f)
        profile_image = upload_file(file ,up_name,'profile-image',2)
        user = db.query(User).filter(User.id == user.id).first()
        if not user:
                return {"message": "User not found"}

        user.profile_minio_url = profile_image
        db.commit()
        # User.profile_minio_url = profile_image
        return JSONResponse(content={"url": profile_image})
    
    else:
        return JSONResponse({"detail":"Invalid file format"})
```

I have written a endpoint for file uploading which will put and get the URL from the minio but how this will be processed by the frontend team. I want to know that is this the way to approach to return the URL and the frontend team will get this without any issues.

Comment: This is a bit vague as we don't know what your frontend depends on or is built like, but, one of the main things to probably consider is the Minio url, is that resource actually accessible without authentication via the API, "externally".

Comment: You may find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73240097/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73843234/17865804) helpful